# Determine if an IQueryable is in memory or not

Tags: c#, reflection, iqueryable

Is it possible to come up with a method that will return true if the IQuerybale object passed in is from an in-memory source and false if not?

So far I've come up with:

```
typeof(EnumerableQuery).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) ||
typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())
```

This is obviously very brittle and while it might work in my test case, I'd like something more resilient ideally.

Comment: what does "in memory" mean?

Comment: Something that won't result in a database/web/etc query. Your question has prompted me to think what I'm asking for isn't possible in a general sense though.

Comment: It's probably *possible*, but impractical. You could potentially use reflection to dig into the `IQueryable` implementation and see what code the enumerator will execute, but doing so would be pretty difficult, and could potentially require solving the stopping problem . . .

Comment: @JimMischel: Agreed, anything other that picking low-hanging fruit as in my example above would probably be impractical as you say. I was hoping for something that deals with the majority of cases, but even that might not be practical.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326746/how-can-i-determine-if-a-linq-query-is-going-to-be-linq-to-sql-vs-linq-to-objec